# When someone gets upset easily

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

Imagine there is an oversensitive friend who often **easily gets upset** in some cases that rarely bother other people or hurt someone's feelings amd that it's strarting to be annoying. Once you decide to advise him in a friendly manner and inform him that he'd better not be such a touchy / softy / irritable person.

OR

Someone is backbiting and speaking about your friends character to his audience and you unwantedly overhear his conversation.

Following the related cases above, I would be thankful if you could let me know whether the sentences bellow would work in a natural and idiomatic way. If not, then how shall one indicate such messages:

> - Don't be **such a touchy person** / **such a softy**  / **such an irritable person**.
> - He is so **touchy** / **softy** / **irritable**.

P.S. I've taken a look on the similar thread here and looked up all the dictionaries and cannot define where and why each word should be used!

The only difference I found between them is that the word "irritable" is a formal one while the other two are not!

Comment: "Softy" is not used this way in American English that I know of.   The Cambridge dictionary doesn't show it, also.  It sounds too much like "softie" which is used in a very different way --- someone who **can be persuaded**.  [Link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/softie?q=softy)

Comment: How about the other words?

Comment: Responded as an answer.  Enjoy!

Comment: short-tempered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are fine:

> - **irritable**  -- this is more formal
> - **touchy**  -- this is less formal

"*Softy*" is not used this way in American English that I know of. The Cambridge dictionary doesn't show it, also. It sounds too much like "softie" which is used in a very different way --- someone who can be persuaded.  [See here for an example.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/softie?q=softy).

You can say things like:

> - He is very irritable in the morning.
> - He is very touchy when you point out his mistakes.
> - Don't be so irritable when I show you a better way to do something.
> - Don't be so touchy. I'm only trying to help.

As you know, telling someone they are being "touchy" (**oversensitive and irritable**) can itself be "touchy" (**requiring careful handling; delicate**)!